# How to get Windows scheduler and Batch File to run only the Master Git Branch

Tags: python, git, branch, scheduler

I have a python program doing a query and some data manipulation that is run every 5 minutes through a batch file and windows scheduler. I want to also start using Git and Github for better version control as the code base get's more advanced.

My question is, how do I set up the batch file to only run the code on the master branch? If I am in a separate branch doing some development, I assume that it will run the code in the branch that I am currently in.

Thanks! - Also, I would be open to suggestions on how to get away from windows scheduler... The program is taking the data and putting it into a CSV that is then being pulled into Tableau. So, if I could somehow get that process off of my windows scheduler that'd be nice but I suppose that's a separate question.

Comment: You should clone repository for development purposes into some other folder.

Comment: And then I can push the clone to the "main" repo when I am ready?